# Have the endHourTime of my event in my calendar iOS : Obj-C

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, events, ekeventstore

I would like to have the actual event, which is synchronised on my calendar app.

The actual event is the event which is happening now.

I would like, at first, to make an app which tells me how much time remains before the end of my event.
The event is my calendar synchronized to my iphone.

In my Main.StoryBoard, I declared a Label:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currentEvent;
```

I declared a EKEventStore:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

From now, I know how to create an event, with start date, end date.. but I would like to retrieve the information from my current event, to be able to do: endDate - timeActual;

Next, in my Label, it will be written :  57 minutes before the end of the event.

```
NSLog(@"%i minutes before the end of the event.", remainTime );
```

I don't know if I'm clear, tell me if you don't understand what I'm asking?
Thank you for your help! :)

**[Update]**

I know how to have the identier of my calendar :

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

 [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                if (!granted)
                                    NSLog(@"Access to store not granted");
                            }];
     NSArray *calendars = [store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

  for (EKCalendar *calendar in calendars)
{
    NSLog(@"Calendar = %@", calendar.description);  
    self.currentEvent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", calendar.calendarIdentifier];
}

EKCalendar *myCalendar = calendars[0];
NSLog(@"My Calendar = %@", myCalendar);

EKEvent *actualEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
```

I know how to set event on my calendar, but no have events which are in my calendar!

Have you got any ideas ?

Comment: please provide more context to your question ;) i.e. what is your overall goal (that is something that a customer would want to pay for)? what have you tried? what did you want to happen? what did you expect? what did happen instead?

Comment: You say "I would like to recover the actual event"; I don't understand what you mean by "actual event". And I don't understand what you mean by "recover", in this case. Has the event been destroyed?